# Как можно стереть border-линию по середине?

Tags: css3, css, jquery, html

Есть рисунок в формате png, он накладывается на середину линии border-top. Так как рисунок просвечивает, то под ним видно линию. Как можно затереть часть линии?!

Comment: скриншот можно? А то я слабо себе представляю эту картину маслом.

Comment: Можно сделать фон рисунку.

Answer (score 1):

1) Для png прописать в стилях 
opacity: 1;

2) Если просвечивает именно "фон" png, то как вариант можно ему задать фон такого же цвета (можно в Photoshop картинкой), как общий фон страницы.